# What is the difference between $z=0$ plane and $26z=0$ plane

Tags: geometry, 3d

I'm using [this](http://onlinemschool.com/math/assistance/cartesian_coordinate/plane/) site to calculate a plane equation. The points are $(2,3,0)$, $(5,1,0)$ and $(6,9,0)$. The result is $26z = 0$ plane.

Is there a difference between $26z =0$ and $z = 0$?

Moreover, when I use $(10,2,8)$, $(15,5,0)$ and $(5,11,4)$, the result is $60x + 60y + 60z -1200 = 0$.
But the plane is simply $x+y+z-20 = 0$ plane.

I can see that dividing both sides of the equation gives me the second planes. However, their normals are different and I wonder if some difference occurs when rotating or hifting them?

Comment: Nothing is different. It's just a rescaled version of the same plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always remember:

> Computers are very, very stupid.

The plane $26z = 0$ is the exact same one as $z=0$. As it appears, the program does not simplify the expression as far as possible (which a human would be expected to do).

Whenever a computer does something for you, always be prepared to interpret the result, if it seems strange ask why it's so, and always consider whether or not the answer is *reasonable*.

(That being said, computers are of course wonderful tools, they just need to be used in a correct way.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, as $0/26=0/1$ The solver they use just created a form which wasnt simplified to lowest terms.